# Failed to connect django with MS sql Server database

Tags: sql-server, django

i have a django project that need to connect with MS SQL server database the problem is that once i runs the server it display this error :

> djago.db.utils.operationalError:('08001','[08001] [microsoft][odbc sql
>   server driver]neither dsn nor server keyword supplied (0)
>   (sqldriverconnect); [08001] [microsoft][odbc sql server driver]
>   Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

that what i did  in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME':   'testDB',
        'HOST':   'DESKTOP-LPD1575\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver':'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }

    }
}
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pyodbc
# from .models import Artist
# Create your views here.


    def connect(request):
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
                                'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                                'Server=ip address;'
                                'Database=testDB;'
                                'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                                'UID=test;'
                                'PWD=test;'
                            )



        cursor = conn.cursor()
        c = cursor.execute('SELECT "first name" FROM t1   WHERE id = 3 ')

        return render (request,'connect.html',{"c":c})
```

Comment: jI checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017) can you try changing your connection string to this format: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)`

Comment: Try SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS (omitting the port number) and see if that works better.

Comment: @dotslash227 there is no port number in the ip address  and its not on local server its on remote server.

Comment: @NalinDobhal i tried your suggestion but still the same error

Comment: @DevDj there should be a port number as well, are you sure that the server address is correct?

Comment: yes i am sure about the server address about the port is the default 1433